# Win 2012 server will not resolve domains using web browser, PING or NSLOOKUP, yet services on server are working

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, windows-server-2012-r2, local-area-network

This is a windows 2012 server running SQL 2014.

The server does not seem to be able to resolve IP address when given a domain name.

The problem first showed itself when I tried to go to a web page to download a client we use to manage our servers. The web browser failed to resolve the address and then tried to go to BING and perform a search. It then failed to resolve the address for BING and returned the following error message:

> "Unable to open search page".

Inputting any domain name results in the same error message. I realize that it is telling me it can't find BING, but it seems to point to not being able to resolve any DNS queries. I get similar results when trying to PING a URL.

PING always returns a NO RESPONSE FROM SERVER, even using addresses like www.google.com. Where as my laptop computer will at least resolve www.google.com to an IP address.

NSLOOKUP also fails to resolve domains to IP address. I always get the generic message "No response from server" All the other servers on our windows domain are resolving domains to IPs just fine. And our back software, MozyPro, is able to backups without any problems. My team and I can connect to the SQL instance running on this server just fine. I've even tried turning off the firewall, but that had no effect.

Comment: So... DNS isn't configured on your SQL server.  Also, you can't ping a url, nor is turning off the firewall the solution to every problem involving a network.  Sheesh.  When all you have's a hammer, the world's a nail, I guess.

Comment: No, DNS is configured, exactly like our other servers. I realize that turning off the firewall is not a solution, merely just to see if it was interfering in some way. It did not have any effect, therefore it is not the fire wall.

Comment: UPDATE: It is something in the group policy. We moved the server out of our Database Server Group Policy and it started working. Moved back in and DNS resolution stopped. Now to track down which group policy it might be.

Comment: UPDATE 2: It turned out to be the "Bypass traverse checking" setting in group policy. We have the SQL service account listed in there. Once we removed that from the group policy, BAM!, SQL server is resolving domain names again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you say that DNS is set up and running properly, but the symptoms you report all suggest DNS.  I was going to suggest you ping your DNS server, but you said in a comment above that you did.  Nevertheless, something is clearly not right.

1. Hexaduple-check (sorry!) the settings on your SQL Server, with `ipconfig /all`.
2. Try to run nslookup on the command line (`nslookup google.com your.dns.ip.address`)
3. Check to see if there is any firewall between the SQL and DNS servers that is blocking TCP and/or UDP port 53.
4. Do you manage the DNS server?  If not, check with the person who does and ask if there is any reason s/he can think of as to why their DNS server would not respond to your SQL Server.

I hope one of those suggestions helps.

Comment: 1. Checked DNS settings again, they are correct
2. NSLOOKUP returns
Server: Unknown
Address: my.DNS.IP
***** UnKnonw can't find google.com no response from server

3. No firewall in-between, I've even disabled the Windows Firewall on SQL server and I get the same response from NSLookup

4. We manage our own DNS and we can't find anything that is specifically blocking the server.

5. I've tried using Test-NetConnection in powershell, trying to connect to port 53, I'm getting "TCP connect to 140.254.XX.XXX:53 failed"

Comment: Its like something on the machine is blocking network connections and it is  not the windows firewall.

Comment: Does your antivirus log say anything interesting?

Comment: Nothing helpful. But I went ahead and disabled the service (we're using endpoint protection), then tried a PING and got the same results. I'm going to try logging on as local admin rather than a Domain Admin and see if things behave differently.

Comment: Same problem when I logon as local admin, darn.

Comment: What happens when you do `nslookup google.com your.dns.ip.address` on a different machine in the same subnet?

Comment: Works perfectly:  
Server: dc6.xxxx.xxxx
Address: 140.254.XXX.XXX  

Non-authoratative naswer:  
Name: google.com  
Addresses: 2067:f8b0:4009:809::200e  
216.58.216.238

Comment: Other than Windows Firewall and Virus Scanner might be blocking this? I've tried shutting down the SQL services one-by-one and running PING, but that had no effect either. (not that I expected it to)

Comment: UPDATE: It is something in the group policy. We moved the server out of our Database Server Group Policy and it started working. Moved back in and DNS resolution stopped. Now to track down which group policy it might be.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have an internal IP address but no DNS setup on the server.  Can you ping Google's DNS server 8.8.8.8 (assuming ICMP is allowed on your firewall) and get a response?  If so, all you need to do is make sure you have your own DNS configured and then run nslookup and see what get's returned.

Comment: See, that's the weird thing. DNS is all setup correctly on the server. This is just one of 12 servers in a domain. They all use the same DNS settings. I've checked the DNS settings like 15 times. Which is why I'm a little frustrated at this point. All the other servers are just fine. This definitely not my first time setting up a server. I can PING things when using an IP address. Though I can't ping 8.8.8.8, outbound ICMP is being blocked. But I did just ping our DNS server using its IP address since it is inside the firewall.

Comment: DNS is setup and running, its like the server refuses to try and resolve domain names. Are there events I should be looking for?